# Русская транскрипция японских слов

Tags: транскрипция

Как правильно писать по-русски японские слова: "митсубиси" или "митсубиши", "Хиросима" или "Хирошима"? Почему в западных транскрипциях пишется буква Ш, а в русских - буква С?

Comment: @Amarie Исправьте, пожалуйста, написание слова "транскрипция", а то бросается в глаза...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько систем транскрибирования японских слов. В русском языке традиционно принята система Е. Поливанова, где в словах перед И и Ё произносится С и ДЗ, а то время как на Западе говорят Ш и ДЖ.
Сейчас верными считаются оба варианта, но ближе к звучанию японской речи все-таки западная версия. Система Поливанова, во-первых, устарела, во-вторых, слишком упрощает звучание.

Answer (score 2):

> > > но ближе к звучанию японской речи все-таки западная версия

Это ошибочное мнение. В японском нет звуков Ш и ДЖ.
С перед гласными переднего ряда произносится слегка шепеляво, но оно очень далеко от Ш. 
При этом я нисколько не покушаюсь на правильность обеих систем транскрибирования. Это вещь - в отличие от фонетики - весьма субъективная.

Answer (score 1):

Соглашаюсь с [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus) - японское произношение очень своеобразно, а различное написание появилось из-за различных путей проникновения слов в русский язык.

Смотрите. Мицубиши, Тошиба, Мацушита являются крупными интернациональными компаниями. Вполне естественно, что их названия были переведены на английский язык и получилось соответственно Mitsubishi, Toshiba, Matsushita. Затем после распада СССР их продукция попала на отечественный рынок и название было переведено с английского. Вот и получился нехарактерное для японского сочетания "ши". Если переводить напрямую с японского, то обычно используется упомянутая выше [система Поливанова](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Проблемным также является сочетание ch, которое по-русски может передаваться как "ч" или как "т". Типичный пример - [провинция Тиба](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)) (Chiba)

Я предлагаю просто в каждом конкретном случае смотреть на классическое написание слова и соответствовать ему. Понятно, что если речь идет о марке Toshiba (записано латиницей), то никому в голову не придет произносить и записывать ее как "Тосиба". Касательно топонимов - ну, посмотрите на карту или в словарь таковых наименований. 100% уверен, что по-русски пишут Хиросима, а никак не Хирошима. Хочу еще напомнить, что во многих культурах имеются свои названия для топонимов. Например, по-русски - Финляндия, по-фински - Suomi (Суоми). Или угадайте какой это город - [Bécs](http://bit.ly/MbOW). И никого это не смущает.

Данная проблема очень похожа на проблему перевода немецких имен на кириллический алфавит - что поделать если в разных языках разный набор звуков и способов их записи.

Еще хочу сказать, что супер, когда используется какой-то определенный стиль для оформления подобных переводов. Т.е. когда эти преобразования (sh->с, ch->т и пр.) идут однообразно. В противном случае, возникают обоснованные подозрения в профессионализме автора перевода.

P.S. [[@barbas](/users/1601/barbas)](/users/1601/barbas), ну, так запихайте сей текст в гугль-переводчик и послушайте - в чем проблема?